# Jasypt Symmetric Encryption key

Tags: java, encryption, password-encryption, jasypt

I Found this piece of code on jasypt.org
I want to know what encryptor.setPassword("jasypt") does.
Is it the Cryptographic key? What happens if i don't set the password?
I've been reading about "Keys", how do i find it? Where do i securely store this key?

```
PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setPoolSize(4);          // This would be a good value for a 4-core system
encryptor.setPassword("jasypt");
encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");
```

Comment: That's a lot of questions. Most can be answered by looking into the code of jasypt (it's open source). The last question cannot be answered without a detailed description of your use case, but since you're asking, there is a chance that your use case doesn't make sense.

Comment: Artjom, Im trying to build a symmetric encryption application. And all of the online videos talk about some key. I do not understand what it is. And they ask one to store it securely. Im sure any cryptographic algorithm will use a key. So i wanna know more about it

Comment: A cipher needs a key. A scheme might use a key, but it might also take something else. The PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES scheme takes a password. Please don't confuse keys and passwords.